# Fetching Only UPPERCASE Strings from Column

Tags: sql, oracle

I followed below Query to display only Uppercase strings but facing 1 issue here

```
SELECT SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE(' ' || REGEXP_REPLACE(DESC, '(^[A-Z]|[a-z]|[A-Z][a-z]+|[,])', ''), ' +', ' '), 2, 9999),ID,DESC AS OUTPUT
FROM ( 
    select ID,DESC
    from MASTER where TABLE like 'D%'
)
```

The above query works in below example:

"This is a NUMBER" Result : NUMBER

But fails in below scenario

"A_NUMBER is a number" Result : _NUMBER

Comment: Can you clarify what you actually want - all words within the string that are entirely uppercase? Or just the first word that is?  What did you expect to see for your second example, `A_NUMBER` or just `NUMBER`? More examples and explanation might be helpful.

Comment: why is this question different from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51627330/sql-to-find-upper-case-words-from-a-column)?

Comment: why starting position is 2 in substring

Comment: @Aleksej, Might be due to an extra "_"

Comment: @Aleksej: The result i'm getting is incorrect so started a new thread with Query i had written.

Comment: if the results you've got from the first question are not correct, it's better to edit the original question, clearly stating what's incorrect in the answers you've got, so that people can edit answers and give you a working one

Comment: @AlexPoole: I have a desc column in my table which has below value

This is a Number

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should replace `comma` with `underscore` as in the foloowing routine :

```
create table master( id int, "TABLE" varchar2(35),"DESC" varchar2(100));
insert into master values(1,'Dolphin1','A_NUMBER is a number');
insert into master values(2,'Dolphin2','This is a NUMBER');

SELECT SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE(' ' 
                             || REGEXP_REPLACE("DESC", '(^[A-Z]|[a-z]|[A-Z][a-z]+|[_])', ''), ' +', ' '), 2, 9999) AS OUTPUT
FROM ( 
    select ID,"DESC"
    from MASTER where "TABLE" like 'D%'
);

ID  OUTPUT
1   NUMBER
2   NUMBER
```

[*SQL Fiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/08d8e/7)