# Pattern matching in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to find the capital word/string in the below given statement. The result length should be more than 1.

E.g:

```
The AGE portion of the SEGMENT_ID must equal 01 or 02.
```

Expected result :

```
AGE
SEGMENT_ID
```

I don't need the string 'The' since it has the first letter as capital 'T'

Comment: This looks very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51627330/sql-to-find-upper-case-words-from-a-column)

Comment: It gives me wrong result

Comment: what gives you wrong results?